# Posible SoundManager 2 to play local sound?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, soundmanager2

I am create a music library on Localhost and is it possible to use [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)play a local sound file with path, ex: D:/Music/file.mp3.

Answer (score 0):

<

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" id="play">play</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#play').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  soundManager.setup({
    url: '/js/',
    onready: function() {
      var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'aSound',
        url: 'path/to/file.mp3'
      });
      mySound.play();
    },
    ontimeout: function() {
      // Hrmm, SM2 could not start. Missing SWF? Flash blocked? Show an error, etc.?
    }
  });
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this work with files on the local filesystem? I don't see why it would

Comment: it definitely works.. but you need to provide swf files in /js/ path and the url path for mp3 file should be correct.

Comment: By "local file system", I think the OP means the Users' file system, not the server. I may have misread the question, but a sample path of `D:/Music/...` doesn't look like a server wwwroot

Comment: once open you file with the browser. if it is playing then no issue, that file is playable with sound manager. and give that path here as url.